# valid triangle number under given region

Tags: algorithm

Let the integer x, y, z be the three sides of the triangle.Given three integers X, Y, Z respectively represents the range of values of the three sides. For example, the x can be 1 or 2 or 3 when X = 3.Find the number of valid triangle that can be constructed by x,y,z.

Note:

```
     a. 3,4,5 and 3,5,4 are two different triangles.

     b. x,y,z can be reach 10^9. So traversing algorithm is unreasonable.
```

**Example:**

```
     X = 2 
     Y = 3 
     Z = 3

     Answer: 9
```

Explanation: we have `9` possible triangles here: `(1,1,1) (1,2,2) (1,3,3) (2,1,2) (2,2,1) (2,2,2) (2,2,3) (2,3,2) (2,3,3)`

Comment: Ok, show your own attempts to start with.

Comment: Could you provide some *examples*?

Comment: example : X = 2 ，Y=3，Z = 3. the valid number of triangle is 9. The valid triangles are (1,1,1)(1,2,2)(1,3,3)(2,1,2)(2,2,1)(2,2,2)(2,2,3)(2,3,2)(2,3,3). @Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is a dump of a homework assignment, that shows ZERO effort from the asker.

Comment: you are asking others to do your work. first you should show what you have tried then expect help.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, lets asume x <= y.

So y = x + k, with k >= 0. For the triangle inequality to hold, x + z >= y. So x + z >= x + k. So z >= k.

So z = k + h, with h >= 0.

Now we have that x + z => y, and y + z >= x. We only need to check that x + y >= z, this is x + x + k >= k + h. So 2x >= h.

```
For every possible x:
    for every possible y >= x:
        answer += 2x + 1  // (k + 0, k + 1 ... k + 2x)
```

But this is still O(n^2), so we need to try to remove the second loop. As you might have noticed, we are not using any info from y to sum the answer, as we always do answer += 2x + 1 regardless of y. So we can reduce it to:

```
For every possible x:
    answer += (2x + 1) * (max y - x + 1)
```

This is just the general idea, won´t be solving the entire problem, just giving hints on how to proceed. Note that we are not checking any bounds here, every possible x means x should not go over max y value, and we are not checking if z can reach those values. When (y - x) + 2x > max z, we need to count less, but that can be fixed. You can then do something similar for when y < x (dont do y <= x as we already counted them) and for when z is not the highest value.

Answer (score -1):

I'm suggesting a **brute force** approach here and would recommend that you reduce its complexity by working on this problem. It'll be very helpful if you could share some progress you've already made on your side.

From what I understand, we get the upper bounds/ limits for the values x,y and z can take.

So,

- when x=2, x can be [1,2]
- when y=3, y can be [1,2,3]
- when z=3, z can
  be [1,2,3]

I suggest you can have something like below:

```
count = 0
for every value x in arr_x:
  for every value y in arr_y:
    for every value z in arr_z:
      if triangle inequality is satisfied:
        increment count by 1
return count
```

Comment: "x,y,z can be reach 10^9"; you have *nested loops*, that's why it'll take `1e9 * 1e9 * 1e9 = 1e27` operations; the executing time can well exceed lifetime of the Universe

Comment: Well.. I had subtly mentioned this in my answer as a disclaimer. Thanks for stating it clearly.